# Can't manage to make JPanel show in the JFrame using super.paintComponent(g). Empty JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

So down below we have my code that's supposed to draw out where you've been on a map using longitude and latitude. When started it tries to find the max and min long/lati with a loop that goes through every value.
After that it initializes the arrays and later on loops trough all TrackPoints stored in the list.
Lastly its supposed to paint a line But when the codes executes with main the JFrame is empty. I've tried multiple things but still an empty frame. I'm still new at this so sorry for any inconvenience.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import csv.CSVReader;
import csv.TrackPoint;
import gui.Login;

public class Position extends JPanel {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    CSVReader activity = new CSVReader();
    
    private List<TrackPoint> trackPoints;
    
    double minLat;
    double minLon;
    double maxLat;
    double maxLon;
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        this.trackPoints = activity.getTrackpointList();
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        findMaxMinLongLat();
        // Initialize arrays
        int[] xArray = new int[activity.trackPoints.size()];
        int[] yArray = new int[activity.trackPoints.size()];
        // Loop through all TrackPoints stored in the list

        int i = 0;
        for (TrackPoint tp : trackPoints) {
            xArray[i] = getXPixValue(tp);
            yArray[i] = getYPixValue(tp);
            i++;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawPolyline(xArray, yArray, xArray.length);
        
    }

    private void findMaxMinLongLat() {
        // just to start with some value:
        minLat = activity.trackPoints.get(0).getLatitude();
        minLon = activity.trackPoints.get(0).getLongitude();
        maxLat = activity.trackPoints.get(0).getLatitude();
        maxLat = activity.trackPoints.get(0).getLongitude();
        // Finds min and max:
        for (TrackPoint tp : trackPoints) {
            double lon = tp.getLongitude();
            double lat = tp.getLatitude();
            if (lon > maxLon)
                maxLon = lon;
            else if (lon < minLon)
                minLon = lon;
            if (lat > maxLat)
                maxLat = lat;
            else if (lat < minLat)
                minLat = lat;
        }
    }

    private int getXPixValue(TrackPoint tp) {
        int xPix = (int) (((tp.getLongitude() - minLon) / (maxLon - minLon)) * getWidth());
        return xPix;
    }

    private int getYPixValue(TrackPoint tp) {
        int yPix = (int) (((tp.getLatitude() - minLat) / (maxLat - minLat)) * getHeight());
        yPix = getHeight() - yPix; // To adjust for y-axis going "downwards" in graphics
        return yPix;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.add(new Position());
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What size is the Position panel supposed to be?  You can probably reduce this down to a compilable example and just use some fake data for your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Position panel doesn't have a preferred size. You're adding it to a JPanel that has a default layout of FlowLayout, which will not expand the content.

One fix, use a layout that will fill the content.

```
panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS) );
```

Another way, is to add it to the JFrame directly which has a content pane with a BorderLayout (another layout that will expand your component to fill the space.).